# How can I remove a spcific html meta tag with php?

Tags: php, html, remove-if

I would like to this:
**If** php found this specific meta tag in the html source,then delete from header:

```
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> <meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file=&autostart=true&skinName=newtube&skinURL=https%3A%2F%2Fneocsatblog.info%2Fskinning-sdk%2Ffive%2Fnewtube%2Fnewtube.xml" />
```

I tryed this way, but dosen't work:

```
if ( $fullmeta == '<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> <meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file=&autostart=true&skinName=newtube&skinURL=https%3A%2F%2Fneocsatblog.info%2Fskinning-sdk%2Ffive%2Fnewtube%2Fnewtube.xml" />') {
     $fullmeta="";  
   }
```

The full codeblock where the full meta is declareted:

```
<? 
 $video_url = get_field('video_urlasd');
if (isset($video_url) && $video_url !== "https://") {
  $meta1='<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />';
  $skinURL="https://neocsatblog.info/skinning-sdk/five/newtube/newtube.xml";
  $meta2=' <meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file='.urlencode($video_url).'&autostart=true&skinName=newtube&skinURL='.urlencode($skinURL).'" />';
  $fullmeta=$meta1.$meta2;
  echo $fullmeta;
  }else{
      echo chop($fullmeta,"asd");
  }
   if ( $fullmeta == '<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> <meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file=&autostart=true&skinName=newtube&skinURL=https%3A%2F%2Fneocsatblog.info%2Fskinning-sdk%2Ffive%2Fnewtube%2Fnewtube.xml" />') {
     echo $fullmeta="";  
   }
  ?>
```

I don't know why, because on the HTML source I found it and looks like same as I copied!

Comment: Where do you set $fullmeta? Can you show us that code?

Comment: Yeah okey, I add to the question

Comment: Done,I added to the question

Comment: Remove space in 2 meta tag. or $fullmeta =  $meta1.' '.$meta2;

Comment: Remember also that by echoing $fullmeta = ""; won't actually set your meta tags.

Comment: Your right i'm realy tired at right now, but I trying to fix this mess

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn I need this, when we actualy have videos.
But if we don't, we don't whant thes tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this part of your code

```
if (isset($video_url) && $video_url !== "https://") {
```

with this

```
if (!empty($video_url) && $video_url !== "https://") {
```

Comment: The problem is with both solution :
When we have videos, this methods also delete og video tags.
As you can see I use variable in full codeblock for file url.
I would like to only remove this meta tags, when the file section is empty (`?file=''`);

Comment: @SzántaiÁdám You are right - my mistake. I've changed the solution and provide only that one with the DOM object.

Comment: if I understand correctly for this method we need the every html tags in the source right?

Comment: Yes, you have to provide a HTML source contains tags you want to delete. You can get it when you create it in PHP or with `file_get_contents` function or send it by ajax, etc. Any metod you want use need to provide a string with HTML contains that tags as the input for this solution.

Comment: Is there is a problem with provide complete HTML source? Do you need to get for example only head section and work with it?

Comment: Yeah, it's just cant work, it's so many appostrofs on there with differnd types and with varribels.
I would like to use this on wordpress header.php

Comment: I've changed my solution to not using a DOM but simply to check is `$video_url` not empty.

Comment: Yeah, this solution is working fine, thanks for the tipp!

Answer (score 0):

You could use str_replace for this.

```
$fullmeta = '<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> <meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file=&autostart=true&skinName=newtube&skinURL=https%3A%2F%2Fneocsatblog.info%2Fskinning-sdk%2Ffive%2Fnewtube%2Fnewtube.xml" />';
$html_without_crap =  str_replace($fullmeta,"",$Where_it_needs_to_look);
```

PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I tryed this way, but dosen't work:
`$html_without_crap =  str_replace($fullmeta,"",'<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> <meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file=&autostart=true&skinName=newtube&skinURL=https%3A%2F%2Fneocsatblog.info%2Fskinning-sdk%2Ffive%2Fnewtube%2Fnewtube.xml" />');`